# How can I convert Csv to Json and recieve Post with Php?

Tags: php, json, csv, jsonp

I'm trying to convert Csv to Json with Php. 
This is the Csv source: finance.sina.com. hk/cgi-bin/api/stock.cgi?action=stock&s=1 
The value of 's', like example ablove: s=1, can be substituted with any number in order to recieve different stock's data. 
And I've done this part (truboy.comeze. com/csv2json.php) :

> $set = http_build_query(
>     array(
>         'action' => 'stock',
>          's' => '1'
>       )
>   );
>
> $opts = array('http' =>
>     array(
>         'method' => 'POST',
>         'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
>         'content' => $set
>     )
>   );
>
> $url = "http://finance.sina.com.hk/cgi-bin/api/stock.cgi";
>
> $context = stream_context_create($opts);
>
> $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
>
> echo $result;

This code actually works. However, the value 's' is fixed with '1' and I want 's' to be changeable

Can I do sth. like 'posting data' e.g.**csv2json.php?s=123**  ?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I asked a wrong question, it should be 'get' not 'post'
Anyway, i find my solution

> ```
>    's' => (int)$_GET['s']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want it to be changed?

```
$feed = 123;
$set = http_build_query( array( 'action' => 'stock', 's' => $feed ) );
```

or something like

```
$set = http_build_query( array( 'action' => 'stock', 's' => (int)$_POST ) );
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

> 's' => (int)$_POST

How can I use it?
I enter http://truboy.comeze.com/csv2json.php?s=3 and it's not the expected result